# How to hide toolbar with buttons in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I want to hide the button toolbar in *tinymce*.

How to do that?

Comment: In that case, please go ahead and hide it.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",

  });
 </script>

Comment: Which "bar" do you mean anyways? I think TinyMCE has a bunch of them.

Comment: the simple bar i just want the textarea, hide the button toolbar (all)

Comment: Why are you using TinyMCE if you don't want any of the toolbars?

Comment: because i have a pb with accent when i use a simple textarea but when i use a textarea with Tiny is work

Comment: Using a whole WYSIWYG editor just to avoid some character encoding problems is a silly workaround. How about fixing the normal textarea instead?

Comment: the pb is i using a blob in my database and when i wnt read information the accent is not present i have this charactere :  ?

Comment: Stop using a BLOB type to store text, and sort out your character encoding. I suggest you use Unicode (UTF-8) wherever you can. The reason TinyMCE makes it work is likely because it (stupidly) encodes everything except US-ASCII as HTML entities.

Comment: so how i can store a long text because if i use simple text in my base (Myslq) the mx for a varchar is 255

Comment: Use one of the TEXT types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html

Comment: i just remove the ui.css of tinymce and the toolbar is not shown.or i guess u can just modify the ui.css that might help

Comment: Please add a screenshot so we know what you are taling about...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using tinyMCE 4 you can set the following in the tinymce init:

```
toolbar: false
```

Here is a full blown example of the init if you want a clean editor with no options:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar: false
    });
</script>
```

Comment: menubar is not hidding

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin that will do this either from a link outside of the editor or from the toolbar itself.

http://www.neele.name/pdw_toggle_toolbars/

Download and extract to your /tiny_mce/plugins/ folder

Then add:

```
 $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    plugins : "pdw,your other plugins ... "
    // All of your other configurations
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "pdw_toggle,bold,italic,underline and the rest...
    // Add PDW
    pdw_toggle_on : 1,
    pdw_toggle_toolbars : "2,3,4"
 }
```

Comment: Where: pdw_toggle_toolbars : "2,3,4" is put the rows you want to hide.

Comment: is it made from javascript or using jquery

Answer (score 3):

If `ed` is a reference to your tinymce editor instance, you may use the following jQuery snippet to hide the toolbar:

```
$('#'+ed.id+'_toolbargroup').parent().css('display','none');
```

use

```
$('#'+ed.id+'_toolbargroup').parent().css('display','block')
```

to get it back;

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty fix would be to simply hide it through CSS

```
#my_textarea_id_tbl tr.mceFirst { display:none; }
```

If its just for visual reasons this might be enough.

Answer (score 2):

In tinymce4, inline mode, I use simply:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.getElement().blur();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mceToolbar:eq(1)").hide();
```

will work for you

replace eq(1) with your button container toolbar e.g. eq(2),eq(3),eq(4)..

Answer (score 1):

if you do an inspection on you tree DOM , you will find :

```
<a id="tinyelement_external_close" href="javascript:;" class="mceExternalClose"></a>
```

So add Jquery instruction to have inner HTML as following

```
$('a#tinyelement_external_close').html('Close')
```

You will have :

```
<a id="tinyelement_external_close" href="javascript:;" class="mceExternalClose">Close</a>
```

Refresh you page you find `close` link at top-right of toolbar.
Click on it . Toolbar become hidden .

Answer (score 1):

simple, use 
    theme: 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'none',

Answer (score 1):

we can hide the cut , copy , paste in menu :

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  menu: {
    file: {title: 'File', items: 'newdocument'},
    edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | selectall'}, // | cut copy paste pastetext we can remove it because it won't work
    insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr'},
    view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
    format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
    table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
    tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code'}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/toolbar-configuration-options/) you can hide diffrent things. In your case it would be something like this.

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '#selector',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar: false,
    });
```