# How to hide toolbar and menubar in tinymce6 editor?

Tags: tinymce-6

### **In tinymce5 version we are using.**

```
 var tinyEditor;    
    tinymce.init(
    {
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
            "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen", 
            "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
            "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", 
        ],
        toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough,
        setup : function(ed){
          tinyEditor = ed;
        }
    });
    
    Later on demand we hide menubar,statusbar  as ..    
    
tinyEditor.settings.menubar = false;    
tinyEditor.settings.statusbar = false;
```

In Tinymce 6 version .settings attribute has been removed.

Comment: Please provide the [example] showing what you tried. And do required research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide toolbar with buttons in TinyMCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628187/how-to-hide-toolbar-with-buttons-in-tinymce)

Comment: Did you try `tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  menubar: false
});` per [the documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/menus-configuration-options/)?